# Function that checks primality correction?

Tags: python, function, primes

Function that checks if input is prime.
I know it has been covered many times here, but my code for some reason gives me True for x=32 and I cant figure out why

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else: 
        for i in range(3,x): #Ignore sqrt(x) improvement
            if x%i == 0:
                return False
            else :
                return True
```

Comment: You don't check divisibility by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(3,x):`

This first goes with the number 3. As `32 % 3 != 0`, it returns `True`. Then the function breaks because it has returned a value.

Consider putting `return True` after the for-loop:

```
for i in range(3,x): #Ignore sqrt(x) improvement
    if x % i == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Now if a number is divisible, it will immediately break and return `False`. But if no numbers go into 32, the for-loop will finish, and it will return `True`.

Also, if you are using python 2.x, it will be faster to use `xrange()`, as that returns a generator :).